# Using Haversine formula to solve for a single coordinate X miles away

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am using the [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) to calculate a distance in miles between two `(lat, lng)` coordinate pairs.  (Note: I am aware and okay with limitations in the formula related to the non-spheroidal (ellipsoidal) shape of the Earth.)

I would like to use this formula to solve for *either* a single latitude or single longitude that is due north, east, west, or south of a given coordinate.  This is maybe best illustrated through a diagram; **I have the central red point as given and am trying to solve for the 4 outer red points below**:

[image]

From the central coordinate of (38.0, -77.0), I want to solve (*individually*) for the 4 missing points at each side of the circle pictured, assuming a distance of 5 miles.  So in each equation, I am given a distance and 3 coordinates, and want to solve for the 4th coordinate.

**How can I rework Haversine formula to solve for an individual coordinate given the other 3?**

What I have tried is to use [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html), but the calculation seems to time out, unless I have a symbol wrong somewhere.  I've also tried to invert the formula, but have gotten stuck halfway.

To use the top point (`lat2, -77.0)` as an example, I'm given the [formulas](https://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/haversine/)

```
dlon = lon2 - lon1
dlat = lat2 - lat1
a = (sin(dlat/2))^2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * (sin(dlon/2))^2
c = 2 * atan2( sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a) )
d = R * c (where R is the radius of the Earth) 

lat1 = radians(38.0)
lon1 = radians(-77.0)
lon2 = radians(-77.0)
d = 5.0
```

And want to solve for `lat2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start from the formula:
$$d=2R\arcsin\sqrt{\sin^2\frac{\phi_2-\phi_1}{2}+\cos\phi_1\cos\phi_2\sin^2\frac{\lambda_2-\lambda_1}{2}}$$
So if the longitudes are the same, $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$, then the formula reduces to $$d=R|\phi_2-\phi_1|$$
so $$\phi_2=\phi_1\pm\frac dR$$
You need to check if $\phi_2$ is reasonable (see circles with radii greater than the distance to the poles).

Similarly, to check points at the same latitude, $\phi_1=\phi_2$,
$$d=2R\arcsin\left|\cos\phi_1\sin\frac{\lambda_2-\lambda_1}2\right|$$
From here$$\sin\frac{\lambda_2-\lambda_1}2=\pm\frac1{\cos\phi_1}\sin\frac d{2R}$$
This is once again a simple way to get $\lambda_2$, as long as the magnitude of the right hand side is less than $1$. So careful with large distances and around the poles.

Comment: Where does that initial formula come from? Is it a reduction of the one shown in my question, or from somewhere else?

Comment: @BradSolomon It's from your first link, the last formula in the first section https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula#Formulation

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot find a formula for determining such a point is that the point **may not exist.**

Consider walking, say, 1000 feet south from the north pole along the Greenwich meridian. You're at longitude 0, latitude 89.99...

Your circle of latitude is about 6000 feet long --- just a little over a mile. There's no point on that circle for which the haversine formula will return a distance of $5$ miles. So if you want a point "due east" by 5 miles, there is no such thing (at least if distance is determined by the haversine formula).

It's interesting (to me at least) that at a point just about 2.5 miles from the pole, the "east" and "west" points that you're seeking actually coincide, and very nearly coincide with the only rational choice for a "north" point (except that its longitude will differ from yours by 180 degrees).

Comment: Thank you, but not sure that I follow. In my example, the centroid is smack dab in the middle of northern Virginia. How would it not be possible to solve (at the very least with some reduced degree of accuracy/decimal precision) for points 5 miles due east, west, north, and south of that?

Comment: I believe what I'm after is something like [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/5821) or [this](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

Comment: My point was that if you want to find a formula for something, that formula will always produce *one answer* (unless there's a division by zero, or something like square-roots that some folks might treat as multi-valued). If one *instance* of the problem you've posed has no solution (or multiple solutions), then you're not going to get a formula. You can see this in @Andrei's answer, where the term $d/R$ might be equal to, or much larger than, $2\pi$. If it's a tiny bit less than $2\pi$, then your East point might be just a few feet to the west of you, and vice versa.

Comment: Similarly, in your second formula, you'll be computing arcsine of something, but that "something" might be greater than $1$ or less than $-1$, in which case the arcsine is undefined. If your original problem had said "Oh, and I only need a formula for locations where the longitude is nowhere near $\pm 180$ degrees, and the latitude is between $-60$ and $60$ degrees," **then** there might be some hope of producing a formula for a guaranteed-to-exist correct answer.